# nesting env vars in consul template

Tags: consul-template

I'm struggling to nest env vars in my consul template to get the required results. Any ideas on how this can be achived?

```
  template {
    data = <<EOH
  {{ with secret "cluster/ca/issue/nomad-my-role" "common_name=socat.service.consul" "ip_sans=127.0.0.1" "alt_names={{ env "attr.unique.hostname" }}.node.primary.consul" "ip_sans={{ env "attr.unique.network.ip-address" }}" }}
  {{- .Data.certificate -}}
  {{ end }}
  EOH
    destination   = "local/certificate.crt"
    change_mode   = "restart"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution for anybody interested

```
  template {
    data = <<EOH
  {{$host := env "attr.unique.hostname"}}
  {{$hostStr := printf "alt_names=%s.node.primary.consul" $host}}
  {{$ip := env "attr.unique.network.ip-address"}}
  {{$ipStr := printf "ip_sans=127.0.0.1,%s" $ip}}

  {{ with secret "cluster/ca/issue/nomad-my-role" "common_name=socat.service.consul" $ipStr $hostStr }}
  {{- .Data.certificate -}}
  {{ end }}
  EOH
    destination   = "local/certificate.crt"
    change_mode   = "restart"
  }
```